# How to derive the following result from the uniformly law of large number?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, law-of-large-numbers

For a $n$-dim Brownian motion $B_t=(B_t^1,\dots, B_t^n)$, I would like to ask how to derive the following result from the uniformly law of large number: as $n\to \infty$, the following converges to zero almost surely on $[0,T]^2$,
$$
\sup_{(t,s)\in [0,T]^2}\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum B_t^iB_s^i-E[\frac{1}{n}\sum B_t^iB_s^i]\right|\to 0.
$$

This means
$$
\sup_{(t,s)\in [0,T]^2}\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum B_t^iB_s^i-E[B_t^1B_s^1]\right|\to 0
$$
and we take sup-norm. So $\frac{1}{n}\sum B_t^iB_s^i\to E[B_t^1B_s^1]$.

This question is enough to verify the condition of ULLN and I find one lecture note of this theorem: [http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~arinaldo/Teaching/36709/S19/Scribed_Lectures/Apr23_Addison.pdf](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Earinaldo/Teaching/36709/S19/Scribed_Lectures/Apr23_Addison.pdf)
It seems that we need to check the Rademacher complexity is $o(1)$? How to check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us regard the Brownian motions $B^i$ as i.i.d. random elements in the space $\mathcal X = C([0,T])$ of continuous functions.
Consider the function $f\colon \mathcal X \times [0,T]^2\to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(x; t,s) = x(t) x(s), x\in \mathcal X, (t,s)\in [0,T]^2.
$$
Then:

1. For all $x\in \mathcal X$, $f$ is continuous on $[0,T]^2$, and for all $(t,s)$, $f$ is measurable (moreover continuous) in $x$.
2. For all $x\in \mathcal X$, $(t,s)\in[0,T]^2$, $|f(x; t,s)|\le g(x) := \sup_{t\in [0,T]} |x(t)|^2$, and $$\mathbb{E}[g(B^1)] = \mathbb{E}\sup_{t\in [0,T]} |B_t^1|^2 <\infty.$$

Therefore, by the usual [uniform law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Uniform_law_of_large_numbers),

$$
\sup_{(t,s)\in[0,T]^2}\left|\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n f(B^i;t,s) - \mathbb{E}f(B^1;t,s)\right| = \sup_{(t,s)\in[0,T]^2}\left|\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n B^i_t B^i_s - \min(t,s)\right|\to 0,\quad n\to\infty.
$$

Comment: Thanks! Based on this result, can we say (i) $(1/n)\sum B_t^iB_s^i\to E[B_tB_s]=E[(B_s-B_t+B_t)B_t]=E[B_t^2]=t$ a.s. for $s>t$, (ii) $(1/n)\sum B_t^i\to E[B_t]=0$, and (iii) $(1/n)\sum B_t^iB_t^i\to t$ a.s. ?

Comment: @Hermi, all three fact follow from the usual SLLN.